# Simple code not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello guys I want to show the database on my website using this code which is given below but it's giving me annoying error again and again. I have tried everything but nothing is working it give me same error notice

**Here is the error Notice**

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php on line 15
```

**Here is the PHP Code**

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");

if(!$connect) {
    die("Failed to Connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db ("login")){
        die("Failed to Select DB: ". mysql_error());
    }

    $results = mysql_query ("Select * from users ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        echo $row['name'];
    }
?>
```

I have also tried to replace `mysql_fetch_array($results)` with this `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` and it's also not working please run this code yourself and then give me that code. Thanks

Comment: Does the column `name` exist in the `users` table?

Comment: what does mysql_fetch_array return? make sure the db has the table users

Comment: once  print_r ($row); and show us result

Comment: Check your database table for the name field. Does it exists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also simply do it this way to avoid confusion on the if's

> mysql_connect("localhost","root","123") or die("Failed to Connect");
>
> mysql_select_db ("login") or die ("cannot connect to db");
>
> $results = mysql_query ("Select * from users ");
>
> while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))

```
{
 echo $row['name'];
}
```

Since the error refers to the name, you might want to check your users table if the column name exists.

Comment: Deprecated `mysql_*` functions cannot be the answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var_dump()` to check the result

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        var_dump($row);
    }
```

check the output,  whether field `name` exists

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 

$username=""; // Mysql username 

$password=""; // Mysql password 

$db_name="test"; // Database name 

$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select databse.

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "abcd")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("testDB")or die("cannot select DB");


$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);


//you can then mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_ob

...

?>
```

this will surely help you

Answer (score 0):

Your database "login", table "users" doesn't have a column "name". That could be because of a typo with CaSe sEnsitivitY or other just missing.